Continuous joint distribution implies all sums are continuous?
Let $\mathbf{X}$ be an $n$ dimensional random vector, with probability measure $P$. The CDF $F$ defined as:
$$
F(x_1,\dotsc,x_n) = P(X_1 < x_1, \dotsc, X_n<x_n) 
$$
is absolutely continuous. Now define $S = \sum_{i \in A} X_i$, for some arbitrary set $A$. I'm trying to prove that the CDF of $S$, denoted $F_S$ is also continuous.
Work so far:
Define $R_{\alpha} = \{ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n:\sum_{i \in A} x_i \leq \alpha\}$, then since $F$ is continuous, and has a well defined PDF $p(\cdot)$ we can write $F_S$ as:
$$
F_S(\alpha) = \int_{R_\alpha} p(\mathbf{x})d\mathbf{x}
$$
The last step should be showing that this expression has a limit. It seems reasonable that something like the dominated convergence theorem would work here, but I am not sure how to apply it (since I am interested in the limit wrt $\alpha$).

Okay, absolutely continuous?

But for S I actually only care about proving continuity at one point (say $\alpha = 0$)

$P(S=0)=0$ because any lower dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^{n}$ has Lebesgue measure $0$ (so the integral of the density function over the subspace is $0$)

@geetha290krm yeah that is the right way to go about it. Thanks

Some informal arguments:
Let $H$ by the CDF for components of $X$ whose indices lie in $A$, by letting other coodinates of $F$ go to $\infty$. Let's call the remaining components $Y_1,Y_2,\dots,Y_p$ for $p=\vert A \vert$. So $H$ is continuous.
Let $Z_1=S$ and $Z_i=Y_i$ for $i=2,3,\dots,p$. Then $Z$ and $Y$ has a one-to-one correspondence and $Z$ has CDF
$$
F_Z(\alpha,y_2,\dots,y_p)=H(\alpha-\sum_{i=2}^p y_i, y_2, y_3, \dots, y_p)
$$
which is continous due to continuity of $H$.
Finally, $F_S(\alpha)=F_Z(\alpha,\infty,\dots,\infty)$ following continuity of $F_Z$.
